# What was the British version of the Enigma machine?

Tags: world-war-two, united-kingdom, cryptology

While the Germans were using the Enigma machine, what were the British using to encrypt their messages and was it ever broken?

Comment: If your interested in Germann codes i suggest you look into Fish and tunny, the reason for creating Colossus.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The British had a similar machine known as the [Typex machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typex).  The Wikipedia article is quite in depth, and of particular relevance is the section on "Security and usage" that says:

> Although a British test cryptanalytic attack made considerable
>   progress, the results were not as significant as against the Enigma,
>   due to the increased complexity of the system and the low levels of
>   traffic.

The Crypto Museum has a list of [British cipher machines](http://www.cryptomuseum.com/crypto/uk/index.htm), although I'll admit I've only heard of the Typex, and I don't know what date the others are from.